# How can I get the char for a given UTF-8 code in Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, utf-8, ruby-2.1

I was wondering if there is a way to get the character for a given UTF-8 code ?

E.g.:

```
1103 = > "я"(russian letter)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) with `U` directive (UTF-8 character):

```
[1103].pack('U')
# => "я"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is `"\u{hex}"`, e.g. `"\u{4355}"`. This syntax accepts only hex numbers, not decimal. Syntax U+184B is [the most commonly used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology) one for referencing Unicode characters.